# Strange problem when using HAVING() and Doctrine_Pager

Tags: php, doctrine

My program generates this DQL using echo $q->getDql(); reformated for easier reading:

```
SELECT o.*, t.*, COUNT(t.id) AS num_of_reservations 
FROM Property o 
LEFT JOIN o.Reservation t 
  WITH t.status=? AND 
 ( (t.start_date<=? AND t.end_date>=?) 
  OR (t.start_date>=? AND t.start_date <= ?) ) 

GROUP BY o.id 
HAVING num_of_reservations < o.nr_of_bookings
```

Using PHP unit tests, I get results as expected. However, when I send this Doctrine_Query to Doctrine_Pager, I get this error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p.nr_of_bookings' in 'having clause'**

I tried all combinations like using having('COUNT(t.id)..... ) etc, different SELECT combos, all results picked by $q->execute() are good except when I send it to pager.

Can somebody help me with this? I even tried

```
FROM Property p 
instead of 
FROM Property o
```

no difference at all.

Comment: What query is generated by Doctrine (`getSql()`)? Is this query working?

Comment: One of the combinations I have tried is this (SELECT is shortened):FROM property p 
LEFT JOIN city c ON p.city_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN state s ON c.state_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN country c2 ON s.country_id = c2.id 
LEFT JOIN reservation r ON p.id = r.property_id 
AND ((r.status = "1" AND ((r.start_date <= "2010-10-26" AND r.end_date >= "2010-10-26") OR (r.start_date >= "2010-10-26" AND r.start_date <= "2010-10-29")))) 
 
WHERE (c.name = "Beograd") 

GROUP BY p.id 

HAVING r__0 < p.nr_of_bookings 
ORDER BY c.name ASC, s.name ASC, c2.name

Comment: And it works when I start it in sqlYog.

Comment: To be used in a `HAVING` clause (in MySQL) `o.nr_of_bookings` must be in the `GROUP BY` clause or used in an aggregate function e.g., `SUM(o.nr_of_bookings)` or `GROUP BY o.id, o.nr_of_bookings`

Comment: Is there any drawback of using GROUP BY o.id, o.nr_of_bookings ; I mean, what happens when it is grouped by o.nr_of_bookings? It is only a column with values like 1-5.