# Retrieving records that have a minimal number of related records

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

There is one-2-many relation between Property and Reservation. Property has column called 'nr_of_bookings'. I need DQL that will retrieve only the properties that has COUNT(Reservation) less than Property.nr_of_bookins.

An example: Some Property has nr_of_bookings = 3 . If it has 5 Reservations related, it will not be retrieved. But if it has 2 related Reservations, it will be retrieved.

I tried numerous combinations, but I miss something obviosly. I posted similar question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009158/doctrine-strange-problem-when-using-having-and-doctrine-pager) , but it is better to start from scratch. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your existing DQL query and let's fix it from there. Please post the DQL, not the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
'SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE SIZE(p.reservations) < p.nr_of_bookings'
```

EDIT: The above is for Doctrine 2. For Doctrine 1.2, looking at your code, I'm guessing your `HAVING` clause is referencing something that's not in a group by or the result of an aggregate function. Try something like this:

```
$q = PropertyTable::getInstance()
    ->createQuery('p') 
    ->select('p.*, COUNT(r.id) as num_of_reservations, SUM(p.nr_of_bookings) as num_bookings') 
    ->leftJoin('p.Reservation r') 
    ->groupBy('p.id') 
    ->having('num_of_reservations < num_bookings');
```

You're grouping by `p.id` so `SUM(p.nr_of_bookings)` will be equal to `p.nr_bookings`.

From the MySQL documentation:

> The SQL standard does not permit the HAVING clause to name any column not found in the GROUP BY clause if it is not enclosed in an aggregate function.

Comment: $q = PropertyTable::getInstance()->createQuery('p')
  ->select('p.*, COUNT(r.id) as num_of_reservations')
  ->groupBy('p.id')
  ->leftJoin('p.Reservation r')
  ->having('num_of_reservations < p.nr_of_bookings') ;
  
I would later add some extra conditions like:  

    ->leftJoin('p.Reservation r WITH r.start_date>', date('Y-m-d'))       
  
But once this basic one is written correctly. Thanks

Comment: Oh are you using Doctrine 1.2?

Comment: I am using Doctrine 1.2 . I will try that SIZE(p.reservations) but I can't find any documentation for SIZE command.

Comment: I tried    SUM(p.nr_of_bookings) as num_bookings'   solution, but it didn't give me correct results. When I print_r results, 'num_bookings' is much higher number that it should be. After that, I placed this:   $q->groupBy('p.id,p.nr_of_bookings') ->addHaving('num_of_reservations<p.nr_of_bookings') ;        For a moment, this looks like results are correct based on my Unit tests. Another question; it grouping by nr_of_bookings a good idea?  Does this aggreagate function work on single property or will affect other properties somehow?  Property and Reservations are one-2-many related. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting thing: instead of SUM(p.nr_of_bookings), I placed this: ROUND(p.nr_of_bookings) as num_bookings    This would fullfill Mysql demand for aggreate function and yet, not make any calculations. Also; groupBy('p.id,p.nr_of_bookings') didn't work after all. Can you tell me if something is wrong using that ROUND() aggregate function?

Comment: @Zeljko - `ROUND()` isn't supported in DQL (according to the docs). I just realized that `SUM(p.nr_of_bookings) = nr_of_bookings * num_reservations` because you join on reservations and then group them by id. Try this: `SUM(p.nr_of_bookings) / COUNT(r.id) as num_bookings` and see if it gives you the correct results

Comment: YES, it was exactly what happened. About ROUND() ; interesting thing is this actually works VERY nice. I have written many unit tests and no fails so far. But, I trust your judgement and will also try that other suggestion later. Thanks again...

Comment: @Zeljko - If `ROUND()` works - great! I just couldn't find it in the documentation which is why I made the other suggestion.